# Building an HTML table, TD widths are not even

Tags: html, css, email-templates

I'm currently working on an email template for a client, and I just remembered why I hate coding email templates.

Basically I'm having trouble making 4 TDs space out evenly in the row.

Here's a portion of my code:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" style="padding-bottom:50px;text-align:center;"><a href="#" style="display:inline-block;width:125px;background:red;"><img src="http://fpoimg.com/95x100"/></a></td>
  <td colspan="3" style="padding-bottom:50px;text-align:center;"><a href="#" style="display:inline-block;width:125px;background:blue;"><img src="http://fpoimg.com/95x100"/></a></td>
  <td colspan="3" style="padding-bottom:50px;text-align:center;"><a href="#" style="display:inline-block;width:125px;background:green;"><img src="http://fpoimg.com/95x100"/></a></td>
  <td colspan="3" style="padding-bottom:50px;text-align:center;"><a href="#" style="display:inline-block;width:125px;background:yellow;"><img src="http://fpoimg.com/95x100"/></a></td>
</tr>
```

I have the background colors set just for ease of view.

[Here's my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tenold/yzn15dom/)

As you can see, those columns are not evening out in that row. There's too much space in the middle. I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Any help?

Comment: Just a thought - You could separate the structures out into more tables (nested tables) so you don't have to worry about items in the same columns messing with your colspan widths.

Comment: Yes, it's more code, but worth it in the end. I always do each row as a separate table. Never use colspan in emails. Not worth it.

Comment: Can you set `min-width:125px;` instead of `max-width:125px;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought - You could separate the structures out into more tables (nested tables) so you don't have to worry about items in the same columns messing with your colspan widths.

eg.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One column content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Two column content</td>
          <td>Two column content</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Three column content</td>
          <td>Three column content</td>
          <td>Three column content</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Four column content</td>
          <td>Four column content</td>
          <td>Four column content</td>
          <td>Four column content</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nesting was the only thing that seemed to make them even out: [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tenold/yzn15dom/3/)

Comment: @Corey, Yep, nesting tables will do that for ya ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
table {table-layout: fixed;}
```

That gives you much more control over the table layout, and stops it making decisions on its own.

Comment: This is a email template. so, can't use css, I think.

Comment: I actually have, and that fixes the four images at the bottom. But, that then it makes the 3 images above it uneven. I'm assuming because the table width is 500px it can't exactly split up 3 columns evenly. [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tenold/cbLLjekm/)

Comment: Once the table layout is set to `fixed`, you can set the desired width on each cell. E.g. `<td style="width: 33%">` or `width: 166px` etc.

Comment: @Mr_Green I believe you can use `table-layout:fixed;` in email templates. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @Corey I mean not as shown in this post. no doubt it could be used inline.

Comment: @ralph.m I've tried that, still unable to even out those three images. [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tenold/cbLLjekm/1/)

Comment: Yes, you have an uneven number of px (500/3) so you'll either have to place gaps between cells or have the cells slighty different widths—say 166, 168, 166 px.